# Unable to obtain actual directory for __file__ Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, operating-system, directory

I've been trying to get the location of an open .py file (using Spyder) that will be used to link various files and use the `__file__` name so that any machine can run from its current directory.

The problem is that when I try:

```
location = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

It gives me the error:

`NameError: name '__file__' is not defined`

I bypassed this by calling on the file as a string rather than the name file variable using:

```
location = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname('__file__'))
```

This worked for getting me the parent directory of the file but not the actual folder that the file was in:

```
location = 'C:\Users\......\Scripts'
```

When really the location is in:

```
location = 'C:\Users\......\Scripts\ISO'
```

I've tried various combinations of `abspath` and `dirname` and `realpath` to get the **true** directory that the file is in but I cannot get it.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: it doesn't work in builtin modules or in interactive shell. What is your context? did you delete `__file__` at some point?

Comment: `os.path.dirname('__file__')` returns blank. it just computes the dirname of a filename, which is empty string, and absolute path on that returns the current directory.

Comment: No, `__file__` still exists in the original directory from which it was downloaded. This file was opened using Spyder from opening in the directory if that's what you're asking?

Comment: @HelloToEarth You are using Spyder interactive shell? That probably does not define `__file__` too. Please run python scripts using the `python3` executable. Don't trust IDE or even the python's REPL to be 100% equivalent to running a script

Comment: FYI: if you are in an interactive session you can simply use `os.getcwd()` to get the current directory. There is no `__file__` because you are not executing a file... you are interactively creating commands, so there is no point in having `__file__` around.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on running the scripts, Bakuriu. This was fixed by changing the working directory inside the shell.

Answer (score 0):

Because I was running the script inside the Spyder shell it did not output the proper working directory because the working directory settings were somehow misaligned with the file's path.

This can be solved by `Run -> Configuration per file -> The directory of the file being executed`

But the more effective way of running the script using `__file__` is to run the script from the `python3.X.exe` file in the directory which the script is located.